# Change access modifiers in Resharper generated auto-properties

Tags: c#, resharper

Resharper provides a feature to create and initialize an autoproperty from a constructor parameter.

By default, the generated property is of the form:

```
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to modify the accessors to have this instead?

```
protected int Foo { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I don't think so. There are quire a few things you can set in Resharper, but as far as I can tell the property generation is not linkable to a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked with JetBrains and this is what they said:

> Hi Jesse,
>   No, it is not possible in the currently. You are welcome, however, [to log a feature request in our
>     issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP)

So the answer is: No.

Comment: Should you log a feature request, post the link here :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I filed a [request](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/requests/11670) to JetBrains

Comment: @OlivierBlanc FYI the resource you mentioned before leads to a 404. There is one similar issue out there I could find @ [RSRP-458465 Generate readonly properties](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-458465#u=1461653836660).

Answer (score 1):

To generate this property I guess you are using the **prop** template

So you can either change it, or create a new one of your own

Go to ReSharper Menu -> Templates Explorer

Choose C# and look for **prop** , you can click edit and change it

But maybe the best way is to create a new one if you sometimes want default properties

Click new template and write that

```
protected $TYPE$ $NAME$ { get; private set; }
```

In the shortcut field type what you want, like **prprop** for example and save it.

Now open a file and type prprod, tab twice and you got the protected propertiy with private setter

If you are not using templates or snippets but the "Create auto-property from constructor" it seems it's impossible to change the access modifier, the only way to change it is when you use

Resharper -> Edit -> Generate Code ...

Then from there what you choose to generate you can change access modifiers or choose if it's read only.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't precise enough. I was talking about the generated properties from a constructor parameter, I modified the question accordingly